# How to dynamically change the id of HTML with angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Inside of an ng-repeat I want to do something like this:

```
<div class='col-sm-12' id="playerHolder"><span id="vidPlayerDIV{{$index}}"></span></div>
```

Where the divs are named vidPlayerDiv0, vidPlayerDiv1 and so on

That code doesn't work, however. How can I do this?

Comment: Can I suggest changing the question to something like, "How to dynamically change the `id` of HTML with angularJs".  Concatenating a string and a variable could apply to any language and millions of situations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
id="{{'vidPlayerDiv' + $index}}"
```

Comment: You've got nonmatching quotation marks. Maybe you meant something like this: `id="{{'vidPlayerDiv' + $index}}"` or this: `id="{{\"vidPlayerDiv\" + $index}}"`. But don't ask me, I have no idea what angularjs is.

Answer (score 5):

I create [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3288/) with correct work.

```
  <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
      <span id="{{'vidPlayerDiv' + $index}}">{{'vidPlayerDiv' + $index}}</span>   
  </div>
```

Comment: To prove it works, I added CSS.  [JS Fiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3290/)

Answer (score 0):

This exact code worked for me atleast, there must be an error somewhere else in your code.

```
 <div ng-repeat="number in numbers"><div class="box{{$index}}">Hello </div></div>
```